# How to download PDF files with Playwright? (Python)

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to automate the download of a PDF file using Playwright, I've the code working with Selenium, but some features in Playwright got my attention. The real problem [the documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/)
isn't helpful. When I click on download I get this:
[image]

And I cant change the directory of the download, it also delete the "file" when the browser/context are closed. Using Playwright I can achieve a nice download automation?

Code:

```
def run(playwright):
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(accept_downloads=True)

    # Open new page
    page = context.new_page()

    # Go to http://xcal1.vodafone.co.uk/
    page.goto("http://xcal1.vodafone.co.uk/")

    # Click text=Extra Small File 5 MB A high quality 5 minute MP3 music file 30secs @ 2 Mbps 10s >> img
    with page.expect_download() as download_info:
        page.click("text=Extra Small File 5 MB A high quality 5 minute MP3 music file 30secs @ 2 Mbps 10s >> img")
    download = download_info.value
    path = download.path()
    download.save_as(path)
    print(path)

    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `download.path()` in playwright is just a random GUID (globally unique identifier). It's designed to validate the download works - not to keep the file.

Playwright is a testing tool and imagine running tests across every major browser on every code change - any downloads would quickly take up a lot of space and it would hack people off if you need to manually clear them out.

Good news is you are very close - If you want to keep the file you just need to give the file a name in the `save_as`.

instead of this:

```
   download.save_as(path)
```

use this:

```
   download.save_as(download.suggested_filename)
```

That saves the file in the same location as the script.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that "playwright is a testing tool". It is a browser automation tool ("playwright") as well as a testing tool ("@playwright/test" ). 

Thanks for the answer! 

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is the correct syntax to save the file in other directory? Would it work if instead of `suggested_filename` a path for download to be saved was indicated?

Answer (score 2):

You can save at any location with [download.save_as(path)](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-download#download-save-as)

This worked for me.

```
from pathlib import Path

...
download.save_as(Path.home().joinpath('Downloads', download.suggested_filename))
```

Answer (score 1):

Its good for me:

```
url = config.url  # your file url
response = await page_request.get(url, params={'id': file_id})  #your request
file = await response.body()  # Downloaded file before save
file_name = filename.pdf  #  filename to be saved
open(file_name, 'wb').write(file)
print(f'File {file_name} is saved')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When I tried a similar code, I got the error:

```
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", waiting until "load"
============================================================
```

In retrospect, it's likely because of the fact that I have set my playwright.chromium.launch_persistent_context(user_dir) to "always_open_pdf_externally:true" as in this example:
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/3509
In stead, what I needed to do was to use a try/except method like such:

```
    async with page.expect_download() as download_info:
        try:
            await page.goto("https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", timeout= 5000)
        except:
            print("Saving file to ", downloads_path, file_name)
            download = await download_info.value
            print(await download.path())
            await download.save_as(os.path.join(downloads_path, file_name))
        await page.wait_for_timeout(200)
```

Maybe this helps someone.
It seems there isn't a clean method for this, yet:
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/7822